# How to fix the black screen with canvas.toDataURL() on Safari browser?

Tags: javascript, canvas, video, safari, video.js

I have a video player (video.js) in my application, and a function which takes a snapshot of the video.

The function create a canvas which draws the snapshot and convert the canvas into a DataURL.

But this doesn't work in Safari.

I'm getting a black screen on Safari.

the video tag looks like:

```
<video crossorigin="anonymous" playsinline="playsinline" id="player_2140_html5_api" class="vjs-tech" data-setup="{ &quot;inactivityTimeout&quot;: 0 }" tabindex="-1" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop"></video>
```

This is the function which creates the snapshot:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = 640;
canvas.height = 480;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var video = document.querySelector('video');
ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
this.snapshotVideo = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
```

The generated dataUrl in Chrome is an image.
The generated dataUrl in Safari browser is a black rectangle.

In Safari the output is black instead of an image of the taken snapshot via the video, how can I solve this?

Comment: When is this function called?

Comment: @Kaiido after the video is playing, there will be a button which opens a modal. inside that modal there is a button, pressing the button will call the function.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this problem on iOS...
I used setTimeout function:

```
setTimeout(() => {
   ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
   canvas.toBlob(() => {
     this.snapshotVideo = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
  });
},100);
```

Comment: Great answere. I tested the issue since few Weeks, and only your solution works. +1

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue.  Calling toDataURL on safari 15 up (mac, iPad or iPhone) seems to occasionally return "" blank string. Previous versions of safari work fine.  I've checked that it is not exceeding the browser canvas size limits which would return "data:," but that is not causing the issue and is returning a blank string.

Answer (score 0):

Same here.
The problem seen first time at Safari 15. Before it works well with your code snipped.

See last comments here:
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=181663
or here:
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=229611

Comment: Good news, since last MacOS update functionality is back now, and works fine with Safari Version 15.4 (17613.1.17.1.6)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem on Safari iOS 15.5 & 15.6 for handling image drawing.
After calling drawImage, the toDataURL() always return blank image.
I changed some code to avoid using canvas in the drawImage and use image object as the first parameter.

```
var scrollTop = 100;

var oc2 = document.createElement('canvas');
if (oc2.getContext) {
    var octx2 = oc2.getContext('2d');
    oc2.width = 200;
    oc2.height = 300;

    var img1 = new Image();
    img1.onload = function() {
        octx2.drawImage(img1, 0, scrollTop, 200, 300, 0, 0, 200, 300);
        var bg_data = oc2.toDataURL('image/png');
        if (bg_data) {
            drawing_board.setImg(bg_data);
            drawing_board.initHistory();
        }
    };
    img1.src = oc.toDataURL('image/png');
}
```